# import excel read row by row then insert into database c# with softartisans ExcelWriter

Tags: c#, excel, bulkinsert, spreadsheet-excel-writer

trying to import bulk data from excel sheet with softartisans ExcelWriter.i do not find much sample code to read row by row and insert into database can i get sample code to read and insert row by row in c#

imported excel file saved in temp location and started reading records

try

```
        {

            string temp_file_name = StateManager.NetworkID + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".xls";

            this.import_file_upload_box.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("temp_files") + "\\" + temp_file_name);

            string strConn;

            recct = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project_Details").Range("A2", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project_Details").Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count;



            ExcelApplication xla = new ExcelApplication();

            Workbook wb = xla.Create(ExcelApplication.FileFormat.Xlsx);

            Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

        }

        catch

        {



        }
```

Actual result should read row by row on imported Excel

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do a bulk insert like the example below?

[the code below can be found on this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5942b056-7985-4cc0-9628-6dcbc6f6bda1/bulk-insert-for-loading-xls-excel-files?forum=transactsql)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ImportTest 

SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 

'Data Source=C:\ImportData.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0')...[Sheet1$]
```

Comment: need to validate each column .if its valid then only it has to insert

Answer (score 0):

I generally use OLEDB for this.
 - Import it into a DataTable
 - Do validation
 - Write to Database

```
public static DataTable LoadCSV(string fileName)
        {
            string sqlString = "Select * FROM [" + fileName + "];";
            string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
                + InboundSourceFilePath + ";" + "Extended Properties='text;HDR=NO;'";
            DataTable theCSV = new DataTable();

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(sqlString, conn))
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(theCSV);
                    }
                }
            }
            return theCSV;
        }
```